# How to displey negative values in highcharts js?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I try to draw a chart. Negative values are not drawing. Here is a link of picture: [image]

```
new Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'spline',
    plotBorderWidth: 1,
    zoomType: 'xy',
    panning: {
      enabled: true,
      type: 'xy'
    },
    panKey: 'shift'
  },

  rangeSelector: {
    selected: 1
  },

  title: {
    text: 'David'
  },
  xAxis: {
    min: -1,
    max: 2,
    title: {
      text: "dcjdkjckjdkc"
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: -120,
    max: 120,
    title: {
      text: "dcjdkjckjdkc"
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
    data: [-1, 0, -2, 1],
    type: 'spline'

  }, {
    name: 'black',
    data: dataRealGraph,
  }]

});
```

Comment: Hi @Виталий Бобров, Could you describe the problem more precisely? Here:  http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4995/ everything seems to work correctly.